# Any import PyQt or qwt crash with error code 139 SIGSEGV

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyqt5, qwt

I can't import any module from PyQt5 or qwt in python script (3.5.2). I tried use any recommendation in google, but it doesn't help! This is error on Ubuntu but worked on Windows (OMG!). Please help me. 
Input by valgrind like this:

```
==6645== Invalid read of size 4
==6645==    at 0x5D1C16: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x4E06C6: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528495: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x52DD1A: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x4E3152: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x5B5DA6: PyObject_Call (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x5B6C09: _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x51B758: PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x542B97: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==  Address 0x6066020 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3,868 free'd
==6645==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6645==    by 0x5BBEB3: _PyBytes_Resize (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x4DDFFE: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x4E10EE: PyCFunction_Call (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x5240B3: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x52DD1A: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x4E3152: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==  Block was alloc'd at
==6645==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6645==    by 0x5D22D8: PyObject_Malloc (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x5BB64E: PyBytes_FromStringAndSize (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x4DDFA5: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x4E10EE: PyCFunction_Call (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x5240B3: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x52DD1A: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645== 
==6645== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6645==    at 0x5D1C1F: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x4E06C6: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528495: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x528463: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x52DD1A: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x4E3152: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x5B5DA6: PyObject_Call (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x5B6C09: _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x51B758: PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==    by 0x542B97: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.5)
==6645==
```

Comment: How have you installed the libraries?

Comment: Yes. I'm install all requirements: pyqt5, qwt